# nodogsplash build: undeclared identifier

Tags: linux, debian, make

I want to install nodogsplash and I followed the instructions to download the package. While installing it gave me the following error:

```
$ make
cc  -O0 -g -Wall -Isrc -c src/gateway.c -o src/gateway.o
src/gateway.c: In function ‘main_loop’:
src/gateway.c:257:8: error: ‘MHD_OPTION_LISTENING_ADDRESS_REUSE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
        MHD_OPTION_LISTENING_ADDRESS_REUSE, 1,
        ^
src/gateway.c:257:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'src/gateway.o' failed
make: *** [src/gateway.o] Error 1
```

How to correct this and get this working?

Comment: Perhaps nodogsplash needs a newer version of the libmicrohttpd development library than your system provides?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the version in the latest pi is libmicrohttpd10 (= 0.9.37+dfsg-1+b1), and that's the one also in debians repositories if I'm reading this right.
https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libmicrohttpd-dev

So I think the problem might be somewhere else?

Comment: I suspect that your answer is an answer to OPs question.  The problem is that I only suspect it, I cannot see it.  You need to link `nodogsplash` to `libmicrohttpd`.  And to the error.  One way to do that is to find in `libmicrohttpd` headers the `MHD_OPTION_LISTENING_ADDRESS_REUSE` and the version where it was added.  Otherwise your answer seems completely random :)